# RegEx: How to match specific pages on website that only contain numbers

Tags: regex

I'm using hotjar to record user sessions and analyze funnels for my website.

In order to define my "listing page" step in a conversion funnel, I need to define a regular expression that will match the url format of those listing pages.

My url structure for listing pages is as follows:
www.example.org/123456

Note: All listing pages have exactly 6 numbers and contain no other words or directories in the url. The 6 numbers are random and range from 0 - 9

What would the correct regular expression formula be to match these pages?

Comment: Does it always start with "www.example.org/" ?  If not, what can be the first component?

Comment: Yes, it always starts with www.example.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that every valid url ends with a `.org` and has exactly six digits, you could try this regex: `(?=www\..+\.org\/\d{6}$).+`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gO1iF2/5)

Comment: I checked the demo. Extremely helpful. The explanation box on the right-hand side is what gave me the detailed breakdown. Here's the link to the solution that worked for me: https://regex101.com/r/gO1iF2/6

Comment: Glad it helped. :)